# ASP.NET Core RC2 Can't Find Html Encoder Implementation

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

Can anyone show me an example of how to HTML encode text with the `HtmlEncoder` class in the `System.Text.Encodings.Web` namespace?

I'm converting an ASP.NET Core RC1 project to RC2.  In the RC1 project I'm using the `HtmlEncoder` class in the `Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders` namespace.  But there is no RC2 update for that.

According to [this GitHub post](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/459) `Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders` has been moved to `System.Text.Encodings.Web`.  But the `HtmlEncoder` class in this new namespace is an abstract class and I can't find an implementation of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's got a few static methods to build encoders now.

Here's a simple example:

```
var value = "Hello<br> world";
var encoder = HtmlEncoder.Default;
var result = encoder.Encode(value); // "Hello&lt;br&gt; world"
```

Other methods include:

```
public static HtmlEncoder Create(TextEncoderSettings settings); 
public static HtmlEncoder Create(params UnicodeRange[] allowedRanges);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Ok, now we're even. :-)