# Working with DirectoryServices in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap

I am upgrading my ASP.NET Core RC1 application to RC2. I have some references to `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in some *.cs files so that I can query LDAP. But I have no idea how to add references to it in RC2 in the `Project.json` file. Everything that I try just gives me more errors. Any help is appreciated.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "default"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Linq.Queryable": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using AD with the Identity Auth system or just querying AD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new CoreCLR doesn't support this library, at the moment. There's an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089) about this, where you can find more information and discussion. (A workaround is presented there if you are only using AD for your authentication system.)

If you're only planning on running this app on a Windows server, you could target "net452" for the framework and add the framework assemblies underneath that.

```
"frameworks": {
  "net452": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.DirectoryServices": "4.0.0.0",
      "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.0.0.0"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the workaround I posted on that GitHub thread!  It's served me well.  I was going to suggest reading that but you beat me to it.

Comment: @ClintB Whoa, same Clint B? Thanks for posting it! I ended up using it myself for an in-house application - saved me a lot of headaches.

Comment: Cool!  I'm glad it helped!!  Do you have any insights on my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330500/asp-net-core-rc2-cant-find-html-encoder-implementation)?

Comment: Does this mean that I will have to revert all my dependancies? They all say they dont work in version 4.5.2

Comment: @BinaryNexus Try removing your first dependency element (`Microsoft.NETCore.App`), and the two `System` elements at the bottom.

Answer (score 26):

Just want to say that they just issued a pre-release of the `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` which contains the `System.DirectoryServices` components needed to work directory with active directory. its beta, but its finally out there.

- [NuGet Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility)

Answer (score 19):

Adding to Bastyons answer above, you can install `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in a .NET Core app as a NuGet package (preview version) from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/4.5.0-preview1-25914-04. Once installed, you can create a simple call to authenticate an AD user as follows:

```
public static bool ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password)
{
    try 
    {
        using (var adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOUR_AD_DOMAIN"))
        {
            return adContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Update: This package is now available as a final version from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Comment: A useful overload is `using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOUR_AD_DOMAIN", "CN=Users,DC=AwesomeDepartment,DC=com"))`

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to authenticate users in .NET Core 2.0, you only need to add System.DirectoryServices Nuget package (no need to add Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility nuget package). It is also supported in .NET Standard 2.0

**Note:** I've only used below code in .NET Core 2.2, but the nuget compatibility info indicates that it works in .NET Core 2.0.

To validate password use:

```
var domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
var entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

object isValidPassword = null;
try
{
     // authenticate (check password)
     isValidPassword = entry.NativeObject;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      _logger.Log.Debug($"LDAP Authentication Failed for {domainAndUsername}"); 
      return false;
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to search for user in directory, below should work:

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry) { Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")" };
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

var result = search.FindOne();
```

According to [Github Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31809), System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement isn't yet supported for LDAP. Beyond that, previous info provided by @zdub and @Bastyon still seems valid.

Comment: I was easily able to port existing old .Net framework AD authentication code to .Net Standard code just by referencing Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[LDAP client library for .NET Standard 1.3](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard)**
Compatible .NET runtimes: .NET Core, .NET Framework 4.6, ...
It works against any LDAP protocol compatible directory server (including Microsoft Active Directory).

```
private static bool LoginLdap(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new LdapConnection())
        {
            conn.Connect("<LdapHost>", 389);
            conn.Bind(LdapConnection.Ldap_V3, $"<yourDomain>\\{username}", password);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (LdapException)
    {
        return false;
    }            
}
```

For more info read this issue : [Support for System.DirectoryServices](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089)
It works well for me. (in .NET Core 1.1.1)

Comment: Sadly this library lacks paging support

Answer (score 4):

**Update from 2021**

Everyone's using `System.DirectoryServices` Nuget these days https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices/ which is NET Standard compatible.

Just updating this question b/c the .NET Core world changes so fast (please, MS, slow down)